# git push and pull remote only work with sudo mode

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-20.04, git-push, git-pull

When i use `git pull` it shows error :

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but when i use  `sudo git pull` it show success :

```
Already up to date.
```

This problem only happens in private repo, when i change the visibility to public, i can pull with `git pull` well.
How to make git work with git pull and not need to add sudo.

/home/username/.ssh
[image: git pull]

/root/.ssh

[image]

git remote -v
[image]

i copy id_rsa.pub to github

Comment: possilby ssh key used to authenticate to remote belongs to root?

Comment: how to check this, the repo is private and i try to use ssh-keygen to push project but has same error: "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.". Finally i use sudo ssh-keygen and sudo git pull . It worked. But i want git pull work without sudo

Comment: authentication with keys involves 2 things: generating a key pair (eg ssh-keygen), and then *sending the public key to the party to which you want to authenticate*.  Did you provide git server with the public key of the user or root or both?

Comment: yes, when i change the visibility of repo to public, i can pull with "git pull" well

Comment: @thaovd1712 do you local user has the appropriate keys populated within ~/.ssh ?

Comment: @Jib yes, it saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa (for "sudo git pull" case) and in /home/thaovd1712/.ssh/id_rsa (for "git pull" case)

Comment: @thaovd1712 are the access rights of those files consistent? I mean, they should be only accessible to the owner (-rw------- fr private key) and (-rw-r--r-- for public key)

Comment: @Jib i updated the picture in this question

Comment: @thaovd1712 I bet that git does not know which key to use among the two in your ~/.ssh directory. Take a look at the edit of my first answer (case 2), add a config file and give it an other try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CASE 1**

Check the owner of the `.git` folder. It sounds like you first ran `sudo git clone ...`.

You can change the owner by doing:

```
sudo chown -R $me:$me .git
```

Where `$me` is your user name and group name.

**CASE 2**

In case your troubles come from SSH, make sure your local user has the correct key files populated under `~/.ssh`. If it does not, you may have to take them back from `/root/.ssh`.

NOTE: when managing multiple GIT repositories from multiple servers (and thus using multiple keys) you can ease this by creating a local configuration file which explicit which key is to be used for each servers.

For instance `~/.ssh/config`:

```
host your.server.com
     user git
     hostname you.server.com
     identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note that it is a general format, you may have to replace the server `you.server.com` and the user name `git` to whatever is expected by your remote server.

EDIT:

According to the further details you provided, here is the `~/.ssh/config` file's content:

```
host github.com
     user git
     hostname github.com
     identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Ensure the `~/.ssh/config` file access is `-rw-rw-r--` to your local user.

NOTE: In any case, you must ensure that your local SSH key is known to the server. In order to avoid confusion, (re) upload the SSH key from the local user to the remote.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: drwxrwxr-x  8 thaovd1712 thaovd1712  4096 Thg 10  3 21:00 .git
this is folder git i copy from "ls -l -a"

Comment: owner rights look to be okay ..

Comment: @thaovd1712, any time you find yourself typing "it's not working " here on SO, immedtiatly append the exact error message.

Comment: if this were the case, I'd expect a filesystem level permission error

Comment: @erik258 this have same error with above. I change the visibility of project to public and "git pull" runs well. But i don't want to public it

Comment: I don't know supposed to do with file config in ssh when i have used only one server from github. Have you try git pull or git push to private repo with ssh url.

Comment: @thaovd1712 what is the result of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: i updated picture in the question

Comment: @thaovd1712 updated the configuration file content so that you just have to copy/paste and the try it

Comment: @thaovd1712 Click "answered" so :)